# Fetching images from Firebase child

Tags: firebase, swift3, xcode8

everyone. I have troubles with fetching a chunk of images from a child in my Firebase database. I am doing an iOS project and using swift 3 and XCode. Basically, after all, my "image" variable returns "nil" Please, help me if you can. Here is the code I am using:

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("menu")
        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                let image = dictionary["foodImageUrl"] as? String
                print(image as Any) // this returns nil
```

and an example of a database structure

[image]

I need to fetch all the "foodImageUrl" from all children from the menu node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your snapshot.value is the list of sub items from menu, not the details info of each node, so you have to use [forEach](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#forEach), and then inside each node, use `dictionary["foodImageUrl"] as? String` to get your image

try this

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("menu")
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        for rest in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [FIRDataSnapshot] {
            if let dictionary = rest.value as? [String: AnyObject]{
                let image = dictionary["foodImageUrl"] as? String
                print(image as Any)
            } 
        }
```

Comment: Could you please come up with an example, because I can't get it?

Comment: Yes sir, I have solved that today already. The only thing is you still have to keep this part `if let dictionary = rest.value` with follows `as? [String: AnyObject] `. Thank you for hint anyways!

Comment: @OleksiiDniprovskyi glad to hear that!